# read geoJson without ajax

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I am beginner in Javascript and leaflet. First I made file `geojson.js` like this

```
 var data={

"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": 1,
        "properties": {
            "Name": "Germany",
            "description": "",
            "timestamp": "",
            "begin": "",
            "end": "",
            "altitudeMode": "clampToGround",
            "tessellate": 1,
            "extrude": -1,
            "visibility": -1
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [                     
                        51.329219337279405,
                        10.454119349999928 
            ]
        }
       } 
      ]
     }
```

and access to their coordinates like this

```
points[0] = data.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0];
points[1] = data.features[0].geometry.coordinates[1];
```

which is OK, but I want to make several geojson, store them in the same folder and access to them by url `leaflet/geojson.js`, not throught http or ajax. Something like this:

```
 var data = $.getJSON( "leaflet/geojson.js", function(json) {
   points[0] = json.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0];

 })
```

Can I do it and how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How else do you plan on accessing them if not for AJAX? That `getJSON` call was made for what you're talking about

Comment: I know it. Is there another way in javascript withou ``getJSON``, but with url ``geojson.js``

Comment: can insert as script tag in page, before code that looks for it, set `src="path/to/geojson.js"`

Comment: no, because I have to pass url to constructor ``new L.TileLayer.GeoJSON(geojsonURL, ...``

Answer (score 3):

If you want to store the geojson in a seperate file like they do here http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson-example.html then you are going to have to fetch it somehow in the same way your browser fetches your js file for initializing leaflet.

As charlietfl says, just add as script tag above your script tag exactly as they do in the link I posted. Then you can refer to the data var without using any fetching method as its already fetched on page load. Alternatively just add the var data in the same file as your init script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="leaflet/geojson.js">
    var data = {

        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "id": 1,
                "properties": {
                    "Name": "Germany",
                    "description": "",
                    "timestamp": "",
                    "begin": "",
                    "end": "",
                    "altitudeMode": "clampToGround",
                    "tessellate": 1,
                    "extrude": -1,
                    "visibility": -1
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        51.329219337279405,
                        10.454119349999928
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    };

    var data2 = {
      ...
    };
</script>
<script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([39.74739, -105], 13);
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/{key}/22677/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; 2011 OpenStreetMap contributors, Imagery &copy; 2012 CloudMade',
        key: 'BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707'
    }).addTo(map);

    L.geoJson(data).addTo(map);
    L.geoJson(data2).addTo(map);
</script>
```